# Error in install_hugo() : The Hugo version NA does not seem to exist

Tags: blogdown

When I run `blogdown::install_hugo()`, there was error that the hugo version NA dose seem to exist.

[image]

I have try to use `install_hugo(version = 'the number of the hugo version')`, but the same error was appeared again.

Comment: You may have problems with connecting to Github in R. What's the output of `xfun::github_releases('gohugoio/hugo', 'latest')`? Do you mean `blogdown::install_hugo('0.121.2')` throws *exactly* the same error?